# LDAP server access via VBscript/ADO

Tags: vbscript, ldap, ado

Can ADO access attributes other that ADsPath and Name when bound to an LDAP server?

Below is the code I use to bind to and query a LDAP server on the internet:

```
Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")                     
ado.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
ado.Properties("User ID") = ""                                
ado.Properties("Password") = ""
ado.Properties("Encrypt Password") = False
ado.Open "NameSearch"                                     


serverName = "xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx"                           
filterStr = "(objectClass=*)"     

Set Ol= ado.Execute("<LDAP://" & serverName & ">;" & filterStr & ";ADsPath;SubTree")

While Not Ol
    WScript.Echo Ol.Fields(0).value
    Ol.MoveNext                                        
Wend
```

Also how do assign the search base in the above code to "o= xxxxxx University;c=US"?

Answer (score 3):

See [How To Use ADO to Access Objects Through an ADSI LDAP Provider](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187529).

> The connection object Execute method's
>   CommandText (first object) is an LDAP
>   query composed of four elements
>   separated by semicolons, in the
>   following format:

```
<LDAP://server/adsidn>;ldapfilter;attributescsv;scope
```

> where `adsidn` is the distinguished name
>   (DN) of the starting point for your
>   query expressed ADsPath format with
>   "/" separators and the root of the
>   namespace to the left. You can also
>   use an X.500 style attributed name
>   format with the relative distinguished
>   names separated by commas and the root
>   of the name space to the right.
>
> To return the `ADsPath`, `class`, and `cn`
>   attributes of all the objects in all
>   the recipient containers in an
>   Exchange server, you can use the
>   following CommandText (in URL format):

LDAP:; (objectClass=*);ADsPath,objectClass,cn;subtree

To put it all together,

```
  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

  Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
  conn.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
  conn.Open "ADs Provider"

  Set rs = conn.Execute( _ 
        "<LDAP://server/o=organization/o=xxxxxx University/c=US>;" _
        & "(objectClass=*);ADsPath,objectClass,cn;subtree")

  While Not rs.EOF
     Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Value, rs.Fields(1).Value, _
           rs.Fields(2).Value
     rs.MoveNext
  Wend

  conn.Close
```